# How to populate a html table with an object of array of objects via Javascript/JQuery (Ampersand.js/Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, javascript-objects, ampersand.js

I am trying to populate an HTML table that displays the content by Categories. I need to do this without using JQuery Datatables. So I'm trying to do this with a regular HTML table.

Here is my Object of array of objects:

```
Object {
    Fruits: [
        Apple: { 
           {color: 'red'},
           {healthy: true}
        },
        Orange: {
            {color: 'orange'},
            {healthy: true}
        },
        Grape: {
            {color: 'purple'},
            {healthy: true}
        }
    ],
    Sweets: [
       Candy: {
          {color: 'pink'},
          {healthy: false}
       }
    ],
}
```

I am trying to populate an HTML table that would look something like this (separated by category):

```
______________________________________
| Name     |  Color    |   Healthy?  |
--------------------------------------
|Fruits                              | 
--------------------------------------
| Apple     |     Red  |      True   |
|----------------------|--------------
| Orange    | Orange   |      True   |
|----------------------|--------------
| Grape     | Purple   |     True    |
|----------------------|--------------
| Sweets                             |
|-------------------------------------
| Candy    |   Pink    |      False  |
--------------------------------------
```

I am using Ampersand.js/Angular. I'm filtering the data I need from a collection, and trying to put them in another object in order to use to populate an HTML table.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? Is there an easier way to set up the  data than the object of array of objects?

Comment: This seems easy enough to do through plain JavaScript. What have you tried so far? Are you having any particular problem?

Comment: I have the data being populated in the object of array of objects, but I'm not sure how to actually populate an HTML table to make it look like the above. I know I am going to have to loop through this, but I am using a predefined template for the table. Do I need to override the template in the loop?

Comment: Yes, although your table template is able to identify your data object you'll need to override it. AFAIK there are no predefined methods to throw data objects into html tables. Depending on your template structure and data object programmation, maybe you can add a method to your data object prototype that generates the html, so you'll only need to call that method each time you need to populate a table from any of those objects.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it is possible inside table but we can create bootstrap column and add some custom css to look like a table. Also, instead of having multiple arrays, you can have one single array of objects with additional properties as "type" and "name". Your current data will look like this.

`$scope.data = [{ name:'Apple', color: 'red', healthy: true, type: 'Fruits'},
            { name:'Orange', color: 'orange', healthy: true, type: 'Fruits'},
            { name:'Grape', color: 'purple', healthy: true, type: 'Fruits'},
            { name:'Candy', color: 'pink', healthy: false, type: 'Sweets'}];`

In angularjs, you can group items based on a property if you include angular-filter. Remember, only `orderBy` is available out of box in angular. If you need to use `groupBy` you should include `'angular-filter'` into your app. You can read more details on angular-filter [here](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter).

Hope this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ts3r0hx4/) helps.